# Example of script-src-attr that is not already handled by script-src-elem

Tags: javascript, content-security-policy

What would be an example of a CSP script-src-elem directive allowing a script to be loaded but a script-src-attr directive preventing a function in that script from being executed? If you don't want the js handlers to be executed, why not just prevent the js from being loaded in the first place? I could understand the usefulness of script-src-attr if it operated at the function level, but that is not the case, is it?

Answer (score 2):

```
Content-Security-Policy: script-src-attr 'none'; script-src-elem 'unsafe-inline';
```

will allow inline scripts like `<script> alert('I am inline') </script>` but disallow event handlers in tags like `onclick="alert('I am onclick')"` and javascript-navigation `<a href="window.open('...')"`.

It's much safer than `script-src 'unsafe-inline';` because about 90% XSS are based on badly sanitized user input lead to skip event handlers in tags, for example `<img src=/ onerror="alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))"></img>`.

Otherwise:

```
Content-Security-Policy: script-src-attr 'unsafe-inline'; script-src-elem 'nonce-ebf34fd3';
```

will disallow inline scripts `<script> ... </script>` without `nonce='ebf34fd3'` attribute, but will allow inline event handlers and javascript-navigations.

This is suitable to craft more safe CSP for old sites with a lot of built-in event handlers.

Please note that as for now [only Chrome](https://csplite.com/csp/test231/) supports `script-src-attr` / `script-src-elem` directives. Chromium-based Edge should support these, too.

Comment: Firefox also supports script-src-attr by now.